# Bluetooth Low Energy Advertising Server Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, bluetooth-peripheral

I am creating an android App that acts as a peripheral and sends out a Bluetooth Low energy advertisement. I am using BluetoothGattServer to set up a server for a client device to connect. My main goal is to read an RSSI value from the client. Is it possible for me to use the BluetoothGattCallback as opposed to BluetoothGattServerCallback with the BluetoothGattServer so that i can implement and use readRemoteRssi?

Answer (score 1):

BluetoothGattCallback is related to to a Master
so you wont be able to use it if your phone is acting as a server/slave